# Is it possible to map one key to two commands, doing 2nd command only if first fails

Tags: vim-windows, key-bindings

I want to map the `tab` key to `<c-w>w` to switch windows when there is more than one window open. But if there is only one window but multiple tabs, I want it to detect that there is only one window and to switch tabs instead by mapping to `gt`. Note both commands are in the same mode.

Is this possible? I am asking this one key to map to two different choices and the key only performs the second choice when the first one fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using an [expression-mapping](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#:map-expression) like this:

`nnoremap <expr><silent> <tab> winnr('$')>1 ? "\<c-w>w" : 'gt'`

this makes the mapping basically check, if there are several windows open (`winnr('$')` is greater than 1) and in that case returns <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> else, it returns <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>

**Note**: the double quotation marks are necessary, to make Vim correctly parse the key code `<c-w>`.

In case there exists only one tabpage, you need to add 2 checks, something like this:

`nnoremap <expr><silent> <tab> winnr('$')>1 ? "\<c-w>w" : (tabpagenr('$')>1 ? 'gt' : ":bn\<cr>")`

Comment: Wow!

I tried the exercise and decide to switch buffers if windows and tabs are 1. Could you tell me why this doesn't work? `nnoremap <expr><silent> <tab> winnr('$')>1 ? "\<c-w>w" : tabpagewinnr('$')>1 ? 'gt' : ":bn\<enter>"`. If there are buffers and tabs, it defaults to buffers not tabs.

Comment: because the `?:` expression syntax does not expect several `?` Check `:h expr1`. Will update my answer