# Getting tab and windows movement with one key combination

Tags: key-bindings, vimscript, vim-windows

Recently I found this question: [Is it possible to map one key to two commands, doing 2nd command only if first fails](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/13430/is-it-possible-to-map-one-key-to-two-commands-doing-2nd-command-only-if-first-f)

It's working well, but I'd like it to work this way: when `Alt-l` is pressed, do `ctrl-w` `l`, but only when there is another window to the right. Otherwise, do `gt`. Same applies to `alt-h`.

[image]

Is this even possible? I can't find any {expr}'s that would could allow me to do such things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `winnr()` function to get the current window number and then try to execute your mapping `<c-w>l` in this case. If the window number doesn't change then execute your other mapping, `gt`.

```
function! s:trywincmd(win, other)
  let winnr = winnr()
  execute 'silent! normal! ' . a:win
  if winnr() == winnr
    execute 'silent! normal! ' . a:other
  endif
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> <c-w>l :call <SID>trywincmd("\<lt>c-w>l", "gt\<lt>c-w>t")<cr>
nnoremap <silent> <c-w>h :call <SID>trywincmd("\<lt>c-w>h", "gT\<lt>c-w>t")<cr>
```

Note: Because this is a mapping we need escape `<` as the `<lt>` key-code.

For more help see:

```
:h keycodes
:h winnr()
:h execute
:h :normal
```

Comment: Works wonders, thanks! One improvement I'd make: `nnoremap <silent> <c-w>h :call <SID>trywincmd("\<lt>c-w>h", "gT\<lt>c-w>b")<cr>` so that when going left cursor starts from window to the right